# How to find Max date from Creation Date or Revision Date column from SQL Table?

Tags: sql

```
ID  creationdate    revisiondate
1   27-06-2020 18:18    NULL
2   29-06-2020 05:54    NULL
3   29-06-2020 07:14    NULL
4   29-06-2020 11:43    29-06-2020 11:58
5   29-06-2020 12:00    30-06-2020 04:43
7   30-06-2020 09:11    NULL
8   30-06-2020 09:14    NULL
```

I need to find a ID where (max(creationdate) or max(revisiondate)) which ever is greaater.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the revision date is later than the creation date, you can use `coalesce()` and ordering:

```
select t.*
from t
order by coalesce(revisiondate, creationdate) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that `fetch first 1 row only` is standard SQL but not all databases support it.  Your might prefer `limit 1` or `select top (1)` or some other method.

Comment: Thanks you sir for quick and simple fix